# jQuery Drop-down-menu Displaying Incorrectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, blueprint-css

This page has some divs that jQuery makes into menus.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/QP4BC/27/) is the jsfiddle.

```
<div class="span-24 last">
<div class="span-5 last menu_button">
    <ul id="item_menu" class="ui-menu">
        <li class="ui-menu-item"><a href="#">Select Item Here</a>

            <ul id="item_menu_list" class="ui-menu" style="display:block; position:relative;"></ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

With these parameters:

```
$( "#item_menu" ).menu("collapseAll", null, true );
```

The menus are cleared and reset:

```
$('#item_menu').html("");
$('#item_menu').append("<li class=\"ui-menu-item\"><a href=\"#\">Item Menu</a><ul id=\"item_menu_list\" class=\"ui-menu\" style=\"display:block; position:relative;\"></ul></li>");
```

then populated through a series of calls like this:

```
 $('#item_menu_list').append("<li class=\"ui-menu-item\"><a class=\"ui-corner-all\" id=\"item_menu_list_item1\" href=\"#item1\">Item 1</a></li>");
```

`.menu_button` has the following .css:

```
div
{
    color:#3079D9;
/*  background:#4334ff; */
    border-image-width:0px;
}

#menu
{
    height:32px;
/*  background:#00ccff; */
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #3079D9;
    position: relative;
    z-index:5000;
}

#menu div
{
    position: relative;
    vertical-align:middle;
    z-index: inherit;
}

.menu_button {
    /* padding:10px; */
    position: relative;
    vertical-align:middle;
    /*z-index: inherit;*/
    margin-top:0px;
    color:#F2F2F2;
    background: #5A86BF;
    text-align:center;
    border: 1px solid #3079D9;
    border-image-width:0px;
}
```

The rest of the .css is drawn from Blueprints css or the jQuery-ui css.

I am using v.1.10.3 of the jQuery UI, and v1.10.2 of jQuery.

Whenever I mouse over the dropdown menus, a white space drops down, just like it should, but the text for the menu-items appears a full menu's-width to the right of the menu. Until a few days ago it was working just like it should. But when I switched from jQuery v.1.9.1 because my jQuery tooltips weren't working, my menus broke. Does anyone have any idea what's making this happen?

Let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: can you make a fiddle that demonstrates the issue?  http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: That's a good question, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: I got a jsfiddle replicating the issue here. http://jsfiddle.net/QP4BC/21/

Comment: I'm looking at your fiddle but I cannot see where this is happening `Whenever I mouse over the dropdown menus, a white space drops down, just like it should, but the text for the menu-items appears a full menu's-width to the right of the menu` when I mouse over the the dropdown` I cant get the mouse over to work.  What i'm seeing right now in your fiddle is that the items are running into your item menu div.  Some CSS like `.ui-menu {margin-top: 8px;}` can fix that.  You may need to further clarify what your question is if this is not what your looking for.

Comment: Darn, I must have forgot to update the jsfiddle. That's really irritating.
I updated it: http://jsfiddle.net/QP4BC/27/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifications made to your fiddle

1. Added `#item_menu_list {
   width:188px;   }` to your CSS - (To make your menu links the same size as the menu..  You can modify it as you see fit.)
2. Removed all the classes from your appended `li` elements.  When the menu activates it automatically adds these classes for you.  There were some conflicts which were causing your issue.
3. Removed the `class` and `style` attributes from  your `item_menu_list` element.  `<ul id="item_menu_list"></ul>` the classes and style and automatically added by menu just like your appended elements.
4. Added a `position` attribute to your menu.  `$('#item_menu').menu({ position: { my: "bottom", at: "right-95 top-3" } });`  This lets you adjust where the menu opens I made it so that it opens right below but you can experiment with it.  `$('#item_menu').menu();` defaults to the menu opening to the right.

Here is the fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/QP4BC/31/

Hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/2hxmB/1/ - it's your question in jsfiddle.net, maybe someone help you. I'm didn't understand objective.

html:

`<div class="span-5 last menu_button">
    <ul id="world_menu" class="ui-menu">
      <li  class="ui-menu-item"><a href="#">Select World Here</a>
        <ul id="world_menu_list" class="ui-menu" style="display:block; position:relative;">
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>`

js:

`$( "#world_menu" ).menu("collapseAll", null, true );
$( '#' + menuId ).append( "<li class=\"ui-menu-item\"><a href=\"#\">" + defaultValue + "</a><ul id=\"world_menu_list\" class=\"ui-menu\" style=\"display:block; position:relative;\"></ul></li>" );`

css:

```
body{background-color: #999;} .menu_button {/* padding:10px; */ position: relative; vertical-align:middle; /*z-index: inherit;*/ margin-top:0px;color:#F2F2F2;background: #5A86BF;text-align:center;border: 1px solid #3079D9;border-image-width:0px;}
```